# MAAS with external DHCP or Static assignment

Tags: networking, server, juju, maas, cluster

**TL;DR: How to set up MAAS, without the maas-server providing DHCP?**

I am having a problem with a MAAS cluster setup, since it's on a subnet that already has a DHCP/DNS provider on it, over which I **do not** have control.

My overall goal is to set up the cluster via MAAS and deploy Hadoop via Juju.

---

**8 nodes:** 1 Region and rack controller aka. `master`, 7 slave aka. `01`, `02` ect.

They each have PXE boot enabled. Boot order: Network, USB/CD, HDD

(Power type set to 'Manual' in MAAS, see below)

**Network:**

Gateway: 192.168.X.1

Static IPs can be assigned in the range 192.168.X.16-24, but only in the node's config, not via DHCP provider (Gateway/Router).

DHCP provider gives IPs in the range: 192.168.X.65 - 254. I set this range as 'Reserved dynamic range' in MAAS

---

So my problem begins here:
I see my nodes in 'Device discovery' but from there, I can only add them as a 'Device' not as a 'Machine'.

I can only manually add the nodes to MAAS as Machines, (getting their MAC address is no problem) but they fail to comission; time out.

I (desperately) tried to set them to a static IP address, and add them to MAAS that way, (`/etc/network/interfaces` file) they still fail to comission.

[MAAS troubleshoot - faq](https://docs.ubuntu.com/maas/2.1/en/troubleshoot-faq/) points me at this:

> If you are using MAAS in a setup with an existing DHCP, DO NOT SET UP THE MAAS DHCP SERVER [...]
>
> SOLUTION: You will need to configure your existing DHCP server to point to the MAAS server.

Which is something I can't do in my current situation.

What steps do I need to take to make this work?

---

*This might be a trivial question, but I am a complete beginner in the topic.*

*Ps.: If a static solution is possible, it's good enough for me. In case this problem cannot be solved under the circumstances described above, then I would like to hear a solution that's changing as little of the (physical) setup as possible.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I wrote:

> My overall goal is to set up the cluster via MAAS and deploy Hadoop via Juju.

and

> *Ps.: If a static solution is possible, it's good enough for me. [...]*

The [Juju-docs](https://jujucharms.com/docs/) has a solution to this problem: [Using a "Manual" cloud](https://jujucharms.com/docs/2.2/clouds-manual)

If you know of a better solution, please share your thoughts.